# Entity Framework updating byte[] improperly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm updating image for the record in the database (the server we use doesn't allow image saving in file system) and it updates the image for the first time, but if I want to re-update a picture shortly, even despite the fact that all the code executes without errors, the byte[] in the database is not updated. If I use breakponts and debug the code - the data is being saved.

The first suspicion was the MemoryStream, the fact that it might not have read everything and there is malformed data that is being discarded from the DB, so I moved out the definition for fileBytes and fileName, as well as service call and return, but it didn't help.

It seems as if the EF was caching the data, but I have no proof for the statement at this moment

```
public ImageResponse Post(IFormFile file, int targetId)
        {
            // TODO save content Type
            // TODO save content size
            if (file == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            long size = file.Length;
            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes;
                string fileName;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}{Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)}";
                }
                this.targetService.AddImage(new TargetImage { TargetId = targetId, ImageFile = fileBytes });
                return new ImageResponse
                {
                    Size = size
                };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

```
public GeneralResult AddImage(TargetImage targetImage)
        {
            var entity = this.targets.Find(targetImage.TargetId) ??
                         throw new Exception();
            entity.TargetPictureUrl = targetImage.ImageFile;
            this.targets.Save(entity);
            return new GeneralResult { Success = true };
        }
```

Under the hood it looks like this:

```
 public void Save(DatabaseEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity is T)
            {
                this.Save((T)entity);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"{typeof(T).Name} is required instance type.");
            }
        }
```

and the "entities" is:

```
private DbSet<T> entities;

protected virtual DbSet<T> Entities => this.entities ?? (this.entities = this.context.Set<T>());
```

Comment: Where is your DbContext?  Maybe you are trying to reuse it?

Comment: @Darkonekt I've added that to my question, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: have you tried calling SaveChanges on your context?

Comment: @Darkonekt yes, i've tried it. It seems as if either EF or DB are caching the changes. The first change comes thru, but the 2nd and 3rd are usually failing. Funnily enough it works perfectly fine if i debug it